# Where is the main Firefox binary?

Tags: firefox, binary, firefox-extensions

I want to optimize my graphical experience with multiple plug-ins on Firefox (Specifically CFX) but for that to work, I need to specify the binary of Firefox so that the driver could force the settings onto it. Where is the binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command for that:

```
which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

---

From the man page for `which`:

HICH(1)                    General Commands Manual                   WHICH(1)

```
NAME
   which - locate a command

SYNOPSIS
   which [-a] filename ...

DESCRIPTION
   which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be exe‐
   cuted in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  com‐
   mands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching
   the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.  It
   does not follow symbolic links.
```

Comment: by "symbolic links" they mean shortcuts?

Comment: They mean symbolic links (command `ln`). "shortcuts" is probably windows lingo(?)