# Firefox's binary path

Tags: firefox

How do I find binary path of Firefox ? I'm using the dev edition and the solution I found here [Where is the main Firefox binary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547681/where-is-the-main-firefox-binary) didn't help as the command `which firefox` outputted nothing.

`whereis firefox` outputted the `lib` location within the system which lead me to firefox's plugins.

`which firefox-dev` outputted nothing as well.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Here is a previous question that may answer some of your questions. [How do I install the Firefox Developer Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition/548532)

Comment: @da_kingpin  That really helped. Thank you !